# Dashboard/File Manager where user can can log in, and see/download files

Tags: php, file, security, download

I'm trying to do a management system, where I create some users, I upload some files for each user, and then, the users are able to log in, and access the files, .pdf files that could be viewed or downloaded. Each user should have obviously access to their files! What's the best way to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Use some PHP framework. Yii, Laravel, Symfony ,etc
Step 2: Create your Database and tables:

You would need 4 tables:

1. Users table
2. User-Rights table (holds who has what kind of rights to do what)
3. File Uploads Table (holds what is uploaded, by who and when..)
4. Log table (Holds who viewed, edited and when)

Or ..use any ready-made DMS system built on PHP. You will find a plethora of them online.

1. [openDocMan](http://www.opendocman.com)
2. [SeedDMS](https://www.seeddms.org/index.php?id=2)

Both of these are written in PHP. If you are into learning, you can even look at their code.